# AngularJs Directive : How to delete input field data using delete key

Tags: angularjs

I used this angularjs directive to restrict user to press only numbers . And definitely it works well. But when i use delete key to delete the input field data. It doesn't work for me.So anybody have an idea to allow the delete key for deleting input field data.

Please help me to get this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
app.directive('allowOnlyNumbers', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        elm.on('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.which == 64 || event.which == 16) {
                // to allow numbers  
                return false;
            } else if (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) {
                // to allow numbers  
                return true;
            } else if (event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105) {
                // to allow numpad number  
                return true;
            } else if ([8, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.which) > -1) {
                // to allow backspace, enter, escape, arrows  
                return true;
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                // to stop others  
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

});

Comment: the key code of delete key is `46`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this else if part into your directive.

```
else if (event.which == 46) {
    // to allow delete  
    return true;
}
```

Hope it'll work.